# While doing an exponential search, why do we choose the base of the exponent as 2?

Tags: algorithm, search, language-agnostic

Can we choose any base of our liking or is the base chosen because it provides the maximum efficiency?

I was looking at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_search) algorithm. Which basically gives this:

```
template <typename T>
int exponential_search(T arr[], int size, T key) {
    if (size == 0) {
        return NOT_FOUND;
    }

    int bound = 1;
    while (bound < size && arr[bound] < key) {
        bound *= 2;
    }


    return binary_search(arr, key, bound/2, min(bound + 1, size));
}
```

Or the Python equivalent:

```
def exponential_search(arr, p):
i = 0
while (arr[2 ** i] < p):
    i += 1
binary_search(arr, p, i)
```

As can clearly be seen in the second while loop, they are setting

```
bound *=2
```

Why 2? Why not any other number?

Comment: Meaningless without more context, but probably you are looking at type of binary search - problem is halved for each recursive depth, hence the power of 2.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I added some more context.

Comment: A base 3 variation would just be more complicated for just a small gain.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Why would it be more complicated? I think it will work better with large data sets?

Comment: And it would do worse with smaller datasets.

Comment: But smaller data sets can be easily tackled due to the binary search.

Answer (score 2):

Implementation difficulties aside, the cost for searching for position n with a multiplier of k is log(n)/log(k) + log((k-1)n) + O(1) = log(n)/log(k) + log(n) + log(k-1) + O(1). By increasing k, we can make the constant factor approach but not reach 1, yet the cost is an increase in the constant term. 2 works well enough, I suppose.

Comment: Sorry, but can you please explain how did you arrive at this formula for complexity.

Comment: Also, the [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/npcsipnxjx) of the formula says that the minimum for the complexity comes at around k = 8.387.

Comment: @harshit The best k increases as you increase n. The formula is the exponential search (base k logarithm of n, the first term) plus binary search over (k-1)n elements.

Comment: Sorry, I am not much familiar with this concept of complexity, but shouldn't you multiply the two logarithms. You are exponentially searching AND then binary searching. Shouldn't that follow the [Rule of Product](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)

Comment: @harshit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Using_simpler_operations

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I know about logarithmic identities. The minimum of the function comes at around k=8.387, so why not use that as a base.